Why is this floor drain filling with water?
Floor drain has flooded before and we had people come out and snake the main drain in the upper part of the photo.  I had someone come out and swear that the floor drain and its pipe needed to be jackhammered and replaced.  But they did not even bother removing the floor grate nor the access to the main pipe.
So this morning before the jackhammer arrived I opened both and saw that sure enough, after I sucked up all the water, I ran some faucets, and the drain filled again when water came down the main pipe.
What do you think?  Did I just get a bad set of plumbers? Or do they know something I do not? I only know about gravity and water.

Update:
I sucked up the water, got the grate off, and plunged it.  Then swoosh!  The water cleared out.  I put a host down there and the water just reliably kept flowing just fine.  So, I think I was about to be scammed pretty bad.  I will have a known company come out and snake the main pipe because we do get tree roots every couple of years.


For water to flow, it needs a clean pipe and a slope.  Clogs, broken/collapsed pipes, or a bad slope can cause flooding.  I would like the plumbers to at least check the pipe with snakes and/or cameras before breaking up your floor.  It looks like cast iron pipes are used, so the age might have something to do with their decision.

the concrete form work looks modern.  I'd expect a camera inspection before any talk of jack hammering.  what year is the house?

Has it always done this?

Just done this maybe 3 times in 18 years we have lived here.  House is 50 years old.

I'm betting the drain has roots in it or has collapsed.

@RMDman But big difference - roots = snake, collapsed = dig and replace.

@mann, yeah there is certainly a lesser of 2 evils there.  I had heard of a company that could clean out a collapsed pipe and line it. But that was a few years ago.
